# renamming and tagging to vlans multiple NICs

Tags: server, netplan, vlan

I have a VM with Ubuntu Server 22.04 and i have assigned 4 NICs to this VM. Each NIC will be set manually to a specific network.
What is the best approach to rename each NIC and assig each one to a specific VLAN ID? With netplan or using udev rules? Do i need to set a .yaml for each NIC or set all under the same config.yaml file?